# Error compiling YouCompleteMe for vim

Tags: python, c++, vim, vundle, youcompleteme

From https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe#ubuntu-linux-x64

I ran

```
./install.py --clang-completer --omnisharp-completer --gocode-completer
```

**I'm using Ubuntu Trusty 14 LTSS**

And got the following error: (full dump: http://sprunge.us/COVL)

> /root/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/BoostParts/boost/type_traits/detail/ice_eq.hpp:17:71: note: #pragma message: NOTE: Use of this header (ice_eq.hpp) is deprecated
>    # pragma message("NOTE: Use of this header (ice_eq.hpp) is deprecated")`

General guide for Vim and Vundle: https://realpython.com/blog/python/vim-and-python-a-match-made-in-heaven/

Any ideas?

Comment: That's just a warning, not an error. The real error is: `virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory`... You can try closing as many applications as possible and/or adding more swap space...

Comment: Use that plugin's issue tracker.

Answer (score 2):

You're running out of RAM when trying to install YCM. The easiest way around it would be killing any other RAM-intensive processes. If that doesn't work, you'll need to add swap space. [Here's a good guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04) for adding swap space on Ubuntu, although the steps for other linux distributions are very similar. In short:

```
sudo fallocate -l 4G /swapfile
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

You can verify it worked by running `free -m`.